# Unable to launch XBMC installed on OpenMediaVault on a VirtualMachine

Tags: linux, debian, nas, xorg

I'm wanting to test different distribution to test which OS I will take for my NAS+HTPC.

Just for some context: I want to put a NAS and the HTPC on the same server because my main usage is to put some movies on and display them on the TV.

I installed guest additions [like specified](http://virtualboxes.org/doc/installing-guest-additions-on-debian/)

I added thoses sources:

```
deb http://debian.oppserver.net/xbmc/ wheezy main non-free contrib
deb http://www.deb-multimedia.org stable main non-free
deb http://www.deb-multimedia.org stable-backports main
```

Then I installed the required app:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install deb-multimedia-keyring
apt-get update
apt-get install python xorg xterm xbmc xbmc-addons
```

I've activated the 3D & 2D acceleration in Virtualbox Configuration.

I rebooted the virtual machine.

But when I try to launch XBMC:

```
xinit /usr/bin/xbmc --standalone
```

I've this error

```
XBMC needs hardware accelerated OpenGL rendering.
Install an appropriate graphics driver.

Please consult XBMC Wiki for supported hardware
http://wiki.xbmc.org/?title=Supported_hardware
```

But since I've a 2d/3d emulation and installed the driver, it should work no? Any idea of what is going wrong?

(Please note that I'm not a linux Guru, saddly :( )

Answer (score 0):

All VMs epically fail when it comes to graphics. I havent really found one to even averagely support enough GFx to run certain applications.

Anyway, if you enabled 3D acceleration in your virtual machine settings, and installed the driver, verify that direct rendering is enabled by running:
**glxinfo | grep direct**

Also, to ensure that 3-D applications work on your host, run:
**glxgears**

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response. `glxinfo` returns `Error: Unable to open display`. I've a windows environnement  as host, but it's my home desktop, which has a nvidia 980 GTX with all driver up to date(and I can launch all the games I tried so far), so the host 3d acceleration should not be the issue.